# Dumbed down Powershell web client function to let me post form data easily

Tags: javascript, php, forms, powershell, web-client

Ive been using an Internet Explorer automation script found here:
http://www.pvle.be/2009/06/web-ui-automationtest-using-powershell/

That lets me easily post form data using commands (functions) like this:

```
NavigateTo "http://www.websiteURI/"
SetElementValueByName "q" "powershell variable scope"
SetElementValueByName "num" "30"
SetElementValueByName "lr" "lang_en"
ClickElementById "sb_form_go"
```

The above would let me post values to elements and click to submit the form.

I would like to do the equivalent with Powershell's web client using helper functions.  I haven't found such a script.  The closest I could find was The Scripting Guys, **Send-WebRequest**:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7e7b6bf2-d067-48c3-96b3-b38f26a1d143

which I'm not even sure it does what I expect (since there's no working examples showing how to do what I want).

Anyway, I'd really appreciate some help to get me started to do the equivalent of what I showed up there with working examples (as simple as possible).  A bonus would be to also be able to get a list of element names for a URI in order to know what form elements I want to submit.

PS:  I also need to be able to specify user-agent and credentials; so, examples with these included would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the Invoke-WebRequest commmand? (requires powershell 3.0 or above)  I believe the following would work for submitting the data

```
#POSTing data
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.websiteURI/ `
    -UserAgent 'My User Agent' `
    -Credential $cred `
    -Method Post `
    -Body @{
        q = 'powershell variable scope'
        num = 30
        lr = 'lang_en'
    }
```

For your bonus, the result of Invoke-WebRequest contains a collection of the InputFields on the page, which you can use to get a list of form elements to set.

```
#List input elements
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.websiteURI/ | select -ExpandProperty InputFields
```

Comment: Yes I saw the Inoke-WebRequest cmdlet.  I wasn't sure about how to do the formatting for -body hashtable parameter.  So, how would I specify which button click to press?  There are sometimes multiple buttons to choose from to click when posting data.  EDIT:  Would I simplely add the click element to the -Body hashtable?  So, I would simple add ClickElementById = "sb_form_go" to the last line of the body parameter?

Comment: It would be great to get a real working example searching http://www.google.com/ using "q = Invoke-WebRequest" and posting with the "I'm feeling Lucky" button.

Comment: With pure HTML, the button clicked doesn't really affect the data that's posted back.  What matters is the form the element's in, and the url that form's posting back to.  

If you're dealing with an AJAX site, then things get a bit trickier as they may be doing extra processing over what is just shown in the form.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more - if your app doesn't have any kind of Javascript working on the form then the button pressed actually has no effect on what's sent. The data is just the inputs within the form the button is in, and it submits data to the url provided on the form with the specified method.  If however your page has some kind of AJAX, then it gets trickier - For example ASP.Net will inject the button id in the __EVENTTARGET form value being submitted.  To use Invoke-WebRequest in this scenario is going to require understanding how it translates a button click into the data it sends.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.  I'm still hoping someone would be kind enough to show me a working example of how to submit a search on google.com as if I clicked on the "I'm feeling Lucky" button and -Body @{q = 'Abraham Lincoln'}.

Comment: When you start typing into google, it uses AJAX to show the results in real time, so there's not really a direct equivalent using Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: I'd recommend using a tool such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) which gives you insight into exactly what's being sent over HTTP.  If you run fiddler, double click on a request to view more information on it.  In particular, if you look at the WebForms tab you'll see any form values posted.  These are the values you'd submit in the Body hashtable.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the Fiddler suggestion.  There are video tutorials which really make it easy for me to see/learn exactly whats going on.  Best of all, its all accessible via .NET; although cmdlets are very limited.  BTW thanks to the tips here, I'm already able to post form data based on information I collect using: Invoke-WebRequest http://URI | select -ExpandProperty inputfields | select name, value